# Dynamic Approach to factorial of a number in java, giving NULLPOINTEREXCEPTIN

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, factorial

I developed this code to calculate the factorial in java by the dynamic approach. But it's throwing  an exception NULLPOINTER, here is my code:

public class test {
                   int fact[];int i;
                   int fact(int n) {

               for ( i =2;i<n;i++) {
                 fact[0]=1;
          fact[1]=1;


        fact[i]=fact[i]*fact[1]*fact[0];      

    }return fact[n];
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int N=5; 
        test t=new test();
        int arr[]=new int[N];

        for(int j=0;j<N;j++) {
            arr[j]= t.fact(j);
        }
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
        }
    }

</code></pre>

I am a beginner in java, please can you correct my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need initilize int fact[]   `fact = new int[n + 1];`

Comment: not working,...

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: it worked but the output is not same, its giving me a null array, can you please check my logic in that case.